# Storing elements that have multiple elements

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

What is the best way to store an element that has multiple elements? As in a 6d array. 
I have seen something along the lines of ArrayList(ArrayList(ArrayList(ArrayList))), but don't have a clue as to how or mostly why it would be configure as such or how to access the elements!

As an example, I want to create an array(list) that stores the following information:

house id, house number, street name, residents, owner first name, owner last name

I would like to be able to sort and search on anyone of the sub-elements in the main record element.

What I have done is create an arraylist that contains an arraylist for each of these. Basically I have a class called HouseArray that has a method called CreateArray. From my class GUI, I have

```
houses = new HouseArray();
houses.CreateArray();
```

In class 
       HouseArray, my method CreateArray has

```
ArrayList<Integer> entryID;
ArrayList<Integer> houseNum;
ArrayList<String> streetName;
ArrayList<Integer> residents;
ArrayList<String> firstName;
ArrayList<String> lastName; 

entryID = new ArrayList();
houseNum = new ArrayList();
streetName = new ArrayList();
residents = new ArrayList();
firstName = new ArrayList();
lastName = new ArrayList();
```

and then I use an AddEntry method that puts data into each arraylist.

```
this.entryID.add(12345);
this.houseNum.add(9876);
this.streetName.add("My Street");
this.residents.add(4);
this.firstName.add("John");
this.lastName.add("Jones");
```

I am at a loss at how I would be able to sort this mess and keep the entries synchronized without manually writing a lot of coding to do it all. Also, I want to be able to sum the number of residents that live on a particular streetName or total the number of residents that live in houses owned firstName or lastName.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?
Teaching myself java, so not sure if this counts as homework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As an example, I want to create an array(list) that stores the
>   following information:
>
> house id, house number, street name, house color, owner first name,
>   owner last name

the best approach is to create a `Class` name it `House` and have these attributes as its `state`.

```
class House {

private long houseId;
private long hNo;
private String streetname;
private String color;
private String owner;
private String firstName;
public House(long houseId, long hNo, String streetName, String color, String owner, String firstName){
  //initialize your instance variables here
```

}

```
 public void setHouseId(long houseId){
  this.houseId = houseId;
  }
 //do the same thing for reamining attributes
 //getters and setters for all the attributes.
}
```

now, create a java.util.List which holds House Object.

```
List<house> houseList = new Arraylist<>();
//and populate the list with house objects.
House house1 = new House(123,223,"Bond Street", "Green","James Bond", "James");
list.add(house1);
```

This approach is more `Object-Oriented` way of doing things, as `House` represents an Object which has `state` and `behaviour`.However, if you want to sort your House elements in your arrayList you will have to override equals and hashcode  methods.

Comment: @Rohit Jain Ding, light bulb moment! Thanks! This really sets me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for welcome. Can I get a little more code example as to the setting and getting. I think my code is along the right path, I just need to drop the extra arrays. How do I set the multiple fields of info into each house object? I can't wrap my head around accessing the individual elements of each object.

Answer (score 2):

I think another approach would be create `House` class with those properties.

Instantiate house object and add to arraylist.  You may override equals and hashcode method to perform sorting.

Example:

```
class House{
int houseNum;
String street;

...

//get/set for above properties.
}
```

And add it to list:

```
House houseObj = new House();
list.add(houseObj);
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps me out and sets me in the right direction. I wasn't looking at it objectively (lol)!

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly have you seen `along the lines of ArrayList(ArrayList(ArrayList(ArrayList)))`?? This looks wierd. Never have such kind of design..

If you want to store multiple fields, then create a custom class with all those fields, and have an ArrayList of that class.

For e.g: -

```
class House{
    private int houseId;
    private int houseNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private String owner;
    private String firstName;

    // Constructors

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

And create an `ArrayList` of that class: -

```
List<House> myHouses = new ArrayList<House>();
```

then, to add an object to your list, just use normal `add` method: -

```
myHouses.add(new House(houseId, houseNumber, ....));
```

And to access elements: -

```
for (House myHouse: myHouses) {
    System.out.println(myHouse.getHouseNumber());
}
```

Comment: After days of searching, the only examples I could find are single element arraylists or weird looking off the wall code that made no sense to me. I tried to track down the example, but lost it. It may have involved inner and outer arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not just new to Java. You're new object-oriented programming in general. Are you a student and this is some sort of homework? If it is, please tag it as such.

For your particular data, your class should be House.

```
public class House
{
    int entryId;
    int houseNum;
    String streetName;
    String houseColor;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

Note that in my sample code above, I'm assuming you know enough of java to add the access modifiers like `private`, `public`, etc. and know enough about how to add getter and setter methods, (e.g. `getEntryId()`, `setEntryId(int entryId)`, etc.).

If your objects are actually more complex, you might also be better off creating classes like `Address`, `Person`, etc.

Then with this class, you do create a list:

```
    List<House> houses = new ArrayList<House>();
    House myHouse = new House();
    // insert whatever data you want into "myHouse"
    houses.add( myHouse );
```

To sort the objects in a list, because it's in a `List`, it's part of Java's Collection Framework. You can use the `Collections.sort()` method to sort it. But first you need to understand how it works.

I would suggest you the following pages:

- [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)
- [Java Tutorial: Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)
- [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

Comment: I did an edit, but doesn't look like it took. I am teaching myself and came up with this project as an excercise to better understand arrays with multiple elements. Does this count as homework? Thanks for the info, each tidbit adds up!

Answer (score 1):

> I am at a loss at how I would be able to sort this mess

First, others have already pointed out that you should create a `House` class to organize "this mess".

To sort it, implement the `Comparator` interface, e.g. (assuming your `House` class has a `getEntryID` method):

```
public class HouseIDComparator implements Comparator<House> {

    @Override
    int compare(House house1, House house2) {
        return house1.getEntryID().compareTo(house2.getEntryID());
    }

}
```

This comparator can be passed to `Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)` for sorting. (Note that there is also a sort method with one argument, for lists of types that implement the `Comparable` interface. However, you probably do not want your `House` class to implement that, since it is not obvious on what basis houses should be compared, and you yourself might want to use several different ones.)

As for summing up values, the best way is to loop over all elements in the list and sum up manually.

Comment: Great, thanks. I think I can implement this with some experimentation.

Comment: As far as sorting goes, I want to sort on street name, owner name ( first or last), and/or number of residents...